# XSLT does not create tags within XML Node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to copy all the tags coming from the source xml and create additional xml tags using the source data's element (HostedAppcode). I created XSLT but, I am not getting the desired output. Please see below.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

XML (INPUT)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfServerDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<ServerDetails>
     <ServerName>SE112935</ServerName>
     <InfrastructureAppcode>VLY0</InfrastructureAppcode>
     <HostedAppcode>UBD0,YND0,UGZ0,WWS0</HostedAppcode>
</ServerDetails>
<ServerDetails>
     <ServerName>SE112936</ServerName>
     <HostedAppcode>YND0,UGZ0,WWS0</HostedAppcode>
      <FinancialAppCode>YND0,UGZ0,WWS0</FinancialAppCode>
</ServerDetails>

</ArrayOfServerDetails>
```

XSLT I CREATED:

```
 <?xml version='1.0'?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>

 <xsl:for-each select="ServerDetails">
        <ServerDetails>
              <HostedApplications>
                    <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
                     <xsl:with-param name="list" select="HostedAppcode"/>
                     <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
                   </xsl:call-template>
            </HostedApplications>
      </ServerDetails>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenizeString"> 
<!--passed template parameter --> 
<xsl:param name="list"/> 
<xsl:param name="delimiter"/> 
<xsl:choose> 
      <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)"> 
                      <item> 
                               <!-- get everything in front of the first     delimiter --> 
                              <xsl:value-of select="substring-   before($list,$delimiter)"/> 
                       </item> 
                      <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString"> 
                     <!-- store anything left in another variable --> 
                      <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list,$delimiter)"/> 
                       <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/> 
                      </xsl:call-template> 
       </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:otherwise> 
                     <item> 
                         <xsl:value-of select="$list"/> 
                     </item> `enter code here`
        </xsl:otherwise> 
</xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT I GOT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ArrayOfServerDetails xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<ServerDetails>
        <ServerName>SE112935</ServerName>
        <InfrastructureAppcode>VLY0</InfrastructureAppcode>
        <HostedAppcode>UBD0,YND0,UGZ0,WWS0</HostedAppcode>
</ServerDetails>
<ServerDetails>
       <ServerName>SE112936</ServerName>
       <HostedAppcode>YND0,UGZ0,WWS0</HostedAppcode>
        <FinancialAppCode>YND0,UGZ0,WWS0</FinancialAppCode>
</ServerDetails>
</ArrayOfServerDetails>

<ServerDetails>
         <HostedApplications>
                 <item>UBD0</item>
                 <item>YND0</item>
                   <item>UGZ0</item>
                  <item>WWS0</item>
       </HostedApplications>
</ServerDetails>

<ServerDetails>
           <HostedApplications>
                      <item>YND0</item>
                       <item>UGZ0</item>
                       <item>WWS0</item>
           </HostedApplications>
</ServerDetails>
```

DESIRED (OUTPUT)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfServerDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<ServerDetails>
     <ServerName>SE112935</ServerName>
     <InfrastructureAppcode>VLY0</InfrastructureAppcode>
     <HostedAppcode>UBD0,YND0,UGZ0,WWS0</HostedAppcode>
     <HostedApplications>
                 <item>UBD0</item>
                  <item>YND0</item>
                   <item>UGZ0</item>
                    <item>WWS0</item>
       </HostedApplications>
</ServerDetails>
<ServerDetails>
     <ServerName>SE112936</ServerName>
     <HostedAppcode>YND0,UGZ0,WWS0</HostedAppcode>
     <HostedApplications>
                 <item>YND0</item>
                  <item>UGZ0</item>
                  <item>WWS0</item>
       </HostedApplications>
      <FinancialAppCode>YND0,UGZ0,WWS0</FinancialAppCode>
</ServerDetails>

</ArrayOfServerDetails>
```

Comment: I think you are first copying your nodes and then you create your wanted tags. So restrict your `match="@*|node()" to not Copa your `ServerDetails`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an `xsl:for-each` for the `ServerDetails` element in the template (that matches any node), have it as a separate matching template instead.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ServerDetails">
  <ServerDetails>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <HostedApplications>
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="HostedAppcode"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </HostedApplications>
  </ServerDetails>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenizeString"> 
  <!--passed template parameter --> 
  <xsl:param name="list"/> 
  <xsl:param name="delimiter"/> 
  <xsl:choose> 
    <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)"> 
      <item> 
         <!-- get everything in front of the first     delimiter --> 
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($list,$delimiter)"/> 
      </item> 
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString"> 
          <!-- store anything left in another variable --> 
          <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list,$delimiter)"/> 
          <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/> 
     </xsl:call-template> 
     </xsl:when> 
     <xsl:otherwise> 
        <item> 
           <xsl:value-of select="$list"/> 
        </item> 
    </xsl:otherwise> 
  </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're 'parsing' the `<ServerDetails>` elements twice.  The following code matches all elements and copies their contents, recursively.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
```

That is producing your first set of output, which mirrors the existing XML content.  Then you're traversing all of the `<ServerDetails>` elements again with the for-each, and outputting the content you've specified.

This is untested code below, but basically it should copy all elements as-is except for the HostedAppCode element.  For that one it will copy it first, and then output the desired additional `<item>` elements.

```
<xsl:template match="HostedAppcode">
  <xsl:copy></xsl:copy>
  <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
    <xsl:with-param name="list" select="text()"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Let me try....I am guessing you are suggesting me to do a) add code that displays everything b) Remove Serverdetails tags c) add your template provided  d) keep the rest of code  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>

Comment: I tried the below...it did not work :(     <?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
 
 <xsl:template match="HostedAppcode">
  <xsl:copy></xsl:copy>
 <HostedApplications>
     <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
     <xsl:with-param name="list" select="text()"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
  </HostedApplications>
</xsl:template>

 cont.. below